# Google Calendar V3 hangs when used outside local environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a wrapper for the .net version of the Google Calendar API. The authentication is rather simple and working fine locally (localhost:port).

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               new ClientSecrets
               {
                   ClientId = "The id of my public website",
                   ClientSecret = "The secret of my public website",
               },
               new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
               "user",
               CancellationToken.None).Result;

            // Create the service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential
            });

return service.Events.List("primary").Execute().Items;
```

The issue is, though, when the same code is deployed to production (secrets changed, of course), the application just hangs whenever I try to access the data. There's no exception, no error code, it just keeps loading forever.

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 5):

I am with you. For whatever reason, that also had happen to me. It was a calvary.
The code below works for me. It is my own revision of Google API Simple Task ASP.NET sample.

Add these usings...

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Web;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
```

And these...

```
CalendarService service;
static string gFolder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MyGoogleStorage");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = GetClientConfiguration().Secrets,
            DataStore = new FileDataStore(gFolder),
            Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }
        });

    var uri = Request.Url.ToString();
    var code = Request["code"];
    if (code != null)
    {
        var token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(UserId, code,
            uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("?")), CancellationToken.None).Result;

        // Extract the right state.
        var oauthState = AuthWebUtility.ExtracRedirectFromState(
            flow.DataStore, UserId, Request["state"]).Result;
        Response.Redirect(oauthState);
    }
    else
    {
        var result = new AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, uri, uri).AuthorizeAsync(UserId,
            CancellationToken.None).Result;
        if (result.RedirectUri != null)
        {
            // Redirect the user to the authorization server.
            Response.Redirect(result.RedirectUri);
        }
        else
        {
            // The data store contains the user credential, so the user has been already authenticated.
            service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
                HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential
            });
        }
    }

}

public static GoogleClientSecrets GetClientConfiguration()
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(gFolder + @"\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        return GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It says Redirect Uri Miss match. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you're using `AuthorizeAsync(...).Result`. Using the `Result` property blocks the current thread... and I *suspect* that ASP.NET is trying to schedule the continuation (when authentication completes) in the same thread, leading to a deadlock.

Given that you're blocking anyway, is there any particular reason you want to use the `AuthorizeAsync` call? You'd normally use that in the context of an async method, where you'd have:

```
var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...);
```

(Looking at [`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.WP/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs), I can't see a synchronous alternative at the moment, but that's what you should probably be looking for. My guess is that `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` isn't designed to be used in this situation.)

Admittedly I don't know nearly as much as I probably should about *either* the ASP.NET synchronization context *or* the Google auth API, but hopefully explaining why there's a problem might be a good starting point... you probably want to read [Stephen Cleary's article about synchronization contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx), too.

Answer (score 0):

First of the all: [See Google MVC tutorial](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications)

Step by step

1) Create method in your controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
    {
         //your code
    }
```

2) Create controller :

```
public class AuthCallbackController : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.Controllers.AuthCallbackController
    {
        protected override Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.FlowMetadata FlowData
        {
            get { return new AppFlowMetadata(); }
        }
    }
```

3) Configure Google Console

Answer (score 0):

Execute() is using .Result(). This is a very bad practice that is known to cause deadlocks.

[image]

Simply switch to the ExecuteAsync() method and await the result.