# Google Oauth 2 get access token and refresh token from authorization code

Tags: javascript, c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I got the authorization code with the help of javascript. Now at the server, I need refresh token in exchange. Here is my code.

```
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("code=" + "....."
        + "&client_id=.....&client_secret=...&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fportal%2F&grant_type=authorization_code");
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");

    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

    Stream strm = req.GetRequestStream();
    strm.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    strm.Close();

    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

It raises exception `Bad request` with inner exception as null.

**Update:**

I'm using this in ASP.NET MVC 4 application. Since it is asynchronous operation, I switched to Visual Studio 2013. I modified the code with `await` :

```
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        new[] { 
                        GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify, GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly
                        },
                    "user", 
                    CancellationToken.None
                    ) ;
```

At this statement, it hangs the browser (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25914745/1323304) question). I tried putting logs, no exception and no further execution is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step in Google Authentication is response type **code**. it is a HTTP GET and basically just opens a new browser window.  Once the user Accepts your authentication you they are given an authentication code which they then will have to take back to your application.  It also appears in the browsers title.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code
```

A full explanation of all three steps can be found here [Google 3 legged oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

I am not sure I understand why you are doing it like this.  Using the Google .net client lib is much easier.  NuGet [Google Client lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/) I am not sure which API you are intending to access but Google it with nuget and you should find the proper lib to install.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do it from server side only with the help of your article (http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/). I have a doubt... can we control how user authorization is done? like showing a popup instead of whole new browser tab? or is it out of our control?

Comment: Is there a way to get offline access token? I need to keep the refresh token and use it afterwords.

Comment: You need to make your own implementation of iDatastore to save it filedatastore stores it to %appdata%

Comment: I store it in my database. But when I use the refresh token to get access token afterworks, it does not work.

Comment: You can find an example with db here https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Authentication

Comment: you should open a new question for that.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797153/google-c-sharp-client-library-to-get-refresh-token