# Google C# client library to get refresh token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

This was  my previous code with the help of library.

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { 
                    GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify, GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly
                    },
                "user", 
                CancellationToken.None
                ) ;
```

I'm using this in ASP.NET MVC 4 application. At this statement, it hangs the browser. I tried putting logs, no exception and no further execution is done. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25914745/1323304) question, and since it is asynchronous operation, I switched to Visual Studio 2013. But still the same thing.

Updated code:

```
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { 
                GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify, GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly
                },
            "user", 
            CancellationToken.None
            ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller must also be marked with async and return a Task i.e.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> get(string token){
    //your code here
}
```